# Xaml objects aren't visible in the same Content's view cs file

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

I created a blank `xamarin` forms app Shared project on Visual Studio 2017, in Content view MainPage.xaml added tags for `Label`, `Entry` and `Button` and named them but whenever I try to access them in MainPage.cs.xaml(same content view) Visual Studio marks them as `doesn't exists in the currect context`, but after run they are accessible, eg. `Input` entery in xaml file is accessed in cs file after run (everything is shown in images below).

I've tried many solutions such as deleting obj and bin folders cleaning the solution and rebuilding the solution, but they were useless. I think it's related to another problem I faced before which is Visual Studio doesn't recognize Xamrin.forms namespace, but after build everything is fine and some references are added.

Screenshots:

MainPage.xaml.cs
[image: MainPage.xaml.cs]
MainPage xaml
[image: MainPage xaml]
MainPage.cs after run(`Input` is accessible)
[image: MainPage cs after run]
Before opening cs file
[image: Before opening cs file]
After opening cs file
[image: After opening cs file]
After building
[image: After building]